# Why running memtest.py on gem5 gives error with --cpu-type arguments?

Tags: simulator, gem5

The memtest.py is working fine this way:

```
     build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/memtest.py
```

But when i am giving with arguments its is giving no such option error:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/memtest.py --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Jul 27 2018 14:19:35
gem5 started Sep 17 2018 15:31:03
gem5 executing on 2030044470, pid 5045
command line: build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/memtest.py --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU

Usage: memtest.py [options]

memtest.py: error: no such option: --cpu-type
```

On the other hand se.py and fs.py works fine with additional arguments:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -c /home/prakhar/gem5/tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU
```

Is there any way to run memtest.py with --cpu-type and --mem-type arguments?

Answer (score 1):

As the error informs, there is no such option.

The cpu-type is added for se.py and fs.py on the call to

```
Options.addCommonOptions(parser)
```

You can add both cpu-type and mem-type manually, by doing something along the lines of

```
from m5.util import addToPath, fatal
addToPath('../')
from common import CpuConfig
from common import MemConfig
```

And adding the options to the parser

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()

# Other parser options

parser.add_option("--cpu-type", type="choice", default="AtomicSimpleCPU",
                  choices=CpuConfig.cpu_names(),
                  help = "type of cpu to run with")
parser.add_option("--mem-type", type="choice", default="DDR3_1600_8x8",
                  choices=MemConfig.mem_names(),
                  help = "type of memory to use")
```

The options are then added as *options.cpu_type* and *options.mem_type*. You can check the other examples (in configs/example/) to know if you will need to modify other things to comply with your intentions.

Comment: This will only add  --cpu-type in the input option, but actually i want to run memtest.py with different cpu-types and memory types.For example: --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU --mem-type=DRAMSim2.

Comment: Then you do the same for mem-type (check the function addNoISAOptions in Options.py and import MemConfig). If you need many of the common options, just add the call (i.e., Options.addCommonOptions(parser)). Again, just check the other examples and you will learn what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well i was struggling with this problem and then i found this line in gem5/configs/example/memtest.py:

```
system = System(physmem = SimpleMemory(),cache_line_size = block_size)
```

If you want to run with any other memory ie. DRAMSim2 you can change this line.

```
system = System(physmem = DRAMSim2(),cache_line_size = block_size)
```

This will enable running memtest.py with memory type as DRAMSim2.You can now this as:

```
build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/memtest.py
```

Also to change cpu-type ypu can refer to lines:

```
if options.atomic:
    root.system.mem_mode = 'atomic'
else:
    root.system.mem_mode = 'timing'
```

Default cpu-type is timing and you can change it to atomic by adding --atomic in the command.